# Android / Firebase Project shows Error: "No components defined for this project"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I added Firebase on my project and now when I launch the simulator, it won't open only. It is neither showing any error, it shows

No components defined for this project.

Note: currently not all plugins register their components, so some components may not be visible here.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_news);

    databaseNews = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("news");

    mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newsHeadline);
    nEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newsDescription);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getNewsFloatingButton);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addDescription();

            addHeadline();

        }
    });


 //---------------------------------------------------//

 private void addHeadline(){
    String headLine = mEditText.getText().toString();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(headLine)){
        String id = databaseNews.push().getKey();

        FirebaseNewsStored firebaseNewsStored = new FirebaseNewsStored(id,headLine,description);
        databaseNews.child(id).setValue(firebaseNewsStored);

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Add Head Line", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

    private void addDescription(){
    description = nEditText.getText().toString();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(description)){}
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Add Description", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
 //--------------------------------------------------------//



 package com.example.eeventa;

 public class FirebaseNewsStored {
String newsId;
String newsHeadline;
String newsDescription;

public FirebaseNewsStored(){

}

    public FirebaseNewsStored(String newsId, String newsHeadline, String newsDescription) {
    this.newsId = newsId;
    this.newsHeadline = newsHeadline;
    this.newsDescription = newsDescription;
}

public String getNewsId() {
    return newsId;
}

public String getNewsHeadline() {
    return newsHeadline;
}

public String getNewsDescription() {
    return newsDescription;
}
 }
```

I want to store Headline of news and description in database so I can retrieve it ;(

thanks for your time :)

Comment: show ur gradle files